# HTTP Status Code for detected query string manipulations

Tags: http, query-string, http-status-codes

What is the best HTTP Status Code to use if the server detects that the query string of an URI has been tampered with by the Client?

Comment: It is a client error, so look at the 4xx range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to know what the nature is of the tampering. If you simply want to forbid people from accessing certain urls, `403` is often the most appropriate.

But there may be something more specific.

> Let's say we have a collection of some sort and the items can be accessed via some identifier (.../collection/1). Now let's assume that a user can access the items with identifier between 1 and 100 using a GUI with buttons for instance that sets up the rest call, but not for identifiers > 100. Now if a user manipulates the HTML and the request in the browser and tries to access an item with id = 200, what status code is most appropriate to return?

Lets say `/collection/101`. If the item exists, but the user simply is not allowed to access that item, a `403` is appropriate.

If `101` is *never* accessible by anyone, because for example `101` is actually accessed via `/collection2/101`, a `404` status code is the most appropriate.

If `/collection/101` is not accessible, because the server has a 'state' that needs to change or be resolved first. This state *can* be resolved by the user, and is not an access-control issue, a `409` *may* be appropriate. But I'd say that usually this is not appropriate for requests such as `GET`.

The way you describe it, it sounds more like a permission issue. So then `403` is an easy choice.

Comment: Let's say we have a collection of some sort and the items can be accessed via some identifier (.../collection/1). Now let's assume that a user can access the items with identifier between 1 and 100 using a GUI with buttons for instance that sets up the rest call, but not for identifiers > 100. Now if a user manipulates the HTML and the request in the browser and tries to access an item with id = 200, what status code is most appropriate to return?